# AngularJS - How to deal with ng-repeat with pre-exist items

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-repeat` for a list., but I want to have pre-existing list items that is rendered with Django.

Note: I have set `{[{ }]}` as my AngularJS InterpolateProvider.

**HTML sample**

```
<ul ng-controller="ListController">
    {% for item in existing_list %}
        <li>
            <span>{{item.firstName}}</span>
            <span>{{item.lastName}}</span>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <span>{[{item.firstName}]}</span>
        <span>{[{item.lastName}]}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to handle these items using `ng-controller`

**app.js**

```
function ListController($scope){
    $scope.items = [{firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith"}];
}
```

My question is, how can I add the pre-existing list items generated by Django to be joined with `$scope.items`?

Comment: seems like would make more sense to merge the data as JSON and create all items with ng-repeat. Downside of hard coding part of the list on server is losing ability to use angular to filter list

Comment: Just wondering if you solved this and how. I am currently facing this same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The way how I am doing now is using `ngInit` to inject existing data to scope. So you'll have kind of:

```
<ul ng-controller="ListController" ng-init='items = {% existing_list.toJSON() %}'>
```

(sorry, I don't know how to serialize object to JSON)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have thought of that but I really want to avoid this exact way of printing JSON to be used by js